# Issue with powershel pscustomobject only writing one line to file

Tags: powershell, sorting, format

I am checking a csv file of urls for the status code returning the custom object. After that I want to write it to a file. I have this working correctly, but I want to format the table else the urls are cut off. I got it to work but it doesn't append it to a new line. Also once I get this working I would like to sort by code status so I can get all the 404s to the top.

I have tried format-table and a bunch of other things

```
[pscustomobject]@{
Code = $statusCode
Date = Get-Date -f yyyyMMdd
URL  = $url
} | Format-Table - Autosize
```

This works, but doesnt create a new line each time as it does without.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web.Extensions
$inputPath = "\\Scripts\URLS\test.csv"
$outputPath = "\\Scripts\Results\statusCodeResults.txt"
$urlArray = Import-Csv -Path $inputPath | Select -ExpandProperty urls

function Get-WebStatus {  
  param($urlArray)

  foreach ($url in $urlArray) {
    try {
      $request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method GET
      $statusCode = $request.StatusCode
    }
    catch {
     $statusCode  = $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__
    }

[pscustomobject]@{
Code = $statusCode
Date = Get-Date -f yyyyMMdd
URL  = $url
} 
}
}
Get-WebStatus -urlArray $urlArray | Out-File $outputPath
```

Would like it to look like this but with the URLs showing complete and then eventually sort it as well putting all 404s on top.

```
 Code Date     URL                                             
 ---- ----     ---                                             
 200 20190404 bsca.com/provider/account-tools/login/home.jhtml
 200 20190404 bsca.com/provider/home.jhtml                    
 200 20190404 bsca.com/provider/eligibility-benefits/eligib...
 200 20190404 bsca.com/provider/eligibility-benefits/home.j...
 200 20190404 bsca.com/provider/claims/home-auth.jhtml        
 200 20190404 bsca.com/provider/guidelines-resources/patien...
 200 20190404 bsca.com/provider/claims/search/home.jhtml      
 200 20190404 bsca.com/provider/claims/policies-guidelines/...
 404 20190404 bsca.com/provider/claims/view-rationale/home....
 200 20190404 bsca.com/provider/guidelines-resources/home.j...
```

Comment: Aside from poor formatting and getting the same date for every iteration of the foreach the function is ok. Try the `-Width` parameter of `Out-File`. If you intend to further process data never ever use a `Format-*` cmdlet.

Comment: I'd trade that out-file for export-csv, and add the -append switch. Then you'll have something that's sortable.

Comment: Thank you all! I was able to figure it out when I switched to exporting a CSV. I know its not pretty, but this is my first project with powershell. Appreciate all the advice it helps a ton!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, direct blind answer to your question is to use `-Width` parameter of `Out-File` cmdlet with any suitable value for your needs, e.g.:

```
Get-WebStatus -urlArray $urlArray | Out-File $outputPath -Width 200
```

And for that weird king of semi-bubble sorting you could combine two filtered arrays like this:

```
$url_responses_sorted = @(
    $url_responses | Where-Object -Property Code -EQ 404
    $url_responses | Where-Object -Property Code -NE 404
)
```

But I encourage you to consider saving your `[PSCustomObject]` array in `CSV` format; that way you could any time load your data and work with it using a wide variety of languages/instruments.

```
Export-Csv -Path $outputPath
```

Speaking of PowerShell, you can load your data by `Import-Csv` cmdlet similarly to how you load your $urlArray, and then sort it, group it and filter what you need like this:

```
PS C:\> $url_responses = Get-WebStatus -urlArray $urlArray
PS C:\> $url_responses

Code Date     URL
---- ----     ---
200  20190405 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55521742/issue-with-powershel-pscustomobject-only-writing-one-line...
404  20190405 https://google.com/non-existing-page
200  20190405 https://github.com/
0    20190405 https://non-existing.url/
404  20190405 https://google.com/non-existing-page-2

PS C:\> $url_responses | Sort-Object -Property Code -Descending

Code Date     URL
---- ----     ---
404  20190405 https://google.com/non-existing-page-2
404  20190405 https://google.com/non-existing-page
301  20190405 https://google.com/
200  20190405 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55521742/issue-with-powershel-pscustomobject-only-writing-one-line...
0    20190405 https://non-existing.url/

PS C:\> $url_responses | Group-Object -Property Code

Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    2 200                       {@{Code=200; Date=20190405; URL=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55521742/issue-w...
    1 301                       {@{Code=301; Date=20190405; URL=https://google.com/}}
    2 404                       {@{Code=404; Date=20190405; URL=https://google.com/non-existing-page}, @{Code=404; D...
    1 0                         {@{Code=0; Date=20190405; URL=https://non-existing.url/}}

PS C:\> $url_responses | Where-Object -Property Code -EQ 404

Code Date     URL
---- ----     ---
404  20190405 https://google.com/non-existing-page
404  20190405 https://google.com/non-existing-page-2
```

#### Other considerations (on using `Invoke-WebRequest`)

1. if the webservers from your URL list support `HEAD` requests, than you'll benefit in speed from using that method istead of `GET`:

   ```
   $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri -Method HEAD
   ```
2. if you also interested in redirection codes, than I suggest to use `-MaximumRedirection 0` with `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` (that way script suppress error message about exceeding of the maximum redirection count, which exactly our intention)

   ```
   $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri -Method HEAD -MaximumRedirection 0 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
   ```
3. bandwidths are fat nowdays, so we don't need poping out download progress bar for each request. Where is no any parameter that you could pass to the `Invoke-WebRequest` to suppress progress, but we could temporarily disable it globally like this:

   ```
   $progressPreference = 'silentlyContinue'
   $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri -Method HEAD -MaximumRedirection 0 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
   $progressPreference = 'Continue'
   ```

   of course in your case you should place assigning to that preference variable outside of your loop.

Comment: Thank you for explaining everything! I appreciate it.